# First and second derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The function $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$$ is twice differentiable with $$f(0)=f'(0)=1$$ and $$f(x)*f''(x)+(f'(x))^2=1-\sin x$$, for all real numbers $x$.
I have to prove, that $$f(x)*f'(x)=x+\cos x$$ and $$f(x)=(x^2+2\sin x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ for all x real, where '*' denotes multiplication. Any help would really be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Take the derivative of $f(x)\cdot f'(x)$ with respect to $x,$ and apply the Product Rule. This gives you an initial value problem that you can solve for $f(x)\cdot f'(x).$

Now, take the derivative of $(f(x))^2$ with respect to $x,$ and apply the Chain Rule. Once again, you have an IVP that you can solve for $(f(x))^2,$ which will be enough for you to determine $f(x).$ (Why is that enough?)

Comment: How to use$f(0)=f'(0)$ in order to prove that the constant from the integral is 0?

Comment: Don't forget that both $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$ are equal to $1$! That's much more important here than the fact that they're equal to each other.

Comment: Yes, I know...but here in this case I don't see how to use it.( Maybe I'm too tired)

Comment: Not much more, I have obtained exactly what Semsen wrote, but from there not far away.

Comment: Well, if you correctly applied the Product Rule, you should see that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x)\cdot f'(x)\right]=f(x)\cdot f''(x)+(f'(x))^2,$$ so $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x)\cdot f'(x)\right]=1-\sin x.$$ Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ then gives us $$f(x)\cdot f'(x)=x+\cos x+C_1,$$ where $C_1$ is some constant, right?

Comment: Now, what happens to the equation $$f(x)\cdot f'(x)=x+\cos x+C_1$$ when you let $x=0$?

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Thanks! Now it's clear here. Now, to obtain $f(x)$, write the derivative of$f(x)^2$ and use that $f(x)f'(x)=x+cosx$

Comment: Precisely! You'll once again need to use the fact that $f(0)=1,$ as well. Did you figure out why determining $(f(x))^2$ was enough to determine $f(x)$?

Comment: Oh, I have obtained, that $f(x)^2=x^2+2sinx+1.$Now, I should prove, that $x^2+2sinx+1>0$

Comment: To do that, I recommend that you prove/use the fact that $|\sin x|\le|x|$ for all real $x,$ with  equality only when $x=0.$ So, in particular, $\sin x>-|x|$ for all nonzero real $x,$ and so $$x^2+2\sin x+1> x^2-2|x|+1=(|x|-1)^2\ge0$$ for all nonzero real $x.$ It's immediate that $0^2+2\sin 0+1>0,$ and so $x^2+2\sin x+1>0$ for all real $x.$

Comment: Again, though, I ask: why is knowing $(f(x))^2$ enough to tell us $f(x)$ in this case?

Comment: $x^2+2sinx+1>0$ and the function takes only positive values

Comment: Actually, we need $x^2+2\sin x+1\ge0$ in order to show that there is a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $$(f(x))^2=x^2+2\sin x+1\tag{$\star$}$$ in the first place. But knowing that a function $f$ exists satisfying $(\star)$ isn't enough on its own to determine what $f$ is. We could as have $$f(x)=-\sqrt{x^2+2\sin x+1},$$ for example. However, this does not have the correct initial values, so is not correct. To be continuous, the function must be $$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+2\sin x+1},$$ and we can indeed show that this is never $0,$ so meets all conditions.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:***$$f(x)*f''(x)+(f'(x))^2= \frac{d}{dx} [f(x)*f'(x)]=1-sinx$$
Also
$$\int f(x)*f'(x)dx=1/2*f^2(x)+c$$

Answer (score 0):

It's noticeable that $f(x)f''(x)+f'(x)f'(x)=[f(x)f'(x)]'$, so $f(x)f'(x)=\int{[1-sin(x)]}dx=x+cosx$.

Can you continue?

Comment: So...that integral is x+cosx+c, where c is a constant. We have to prove that c=0. Then, we have to prove that $x^2+2sinx+1>0$ and to obtain that $f(x)=(x^2+2sinx+1)^{1/2}$

Comment: that integral is not clearly x+cosx...